# <ul> with vertical scroll jumps to top in IE9

Tags: internet-explorer-9

I have a tall `<ul>` element that is used as a popover menu. The overflow-y is set to auto, and I can scroll up and down to see the `<li>` elements. In IE9, when I scroll the `<ul>` element down and then mouse over any of the `<li>` elements, the scrollbar jumps straight back to the top. This makes it impossible to select any items at the bottom of a long list.

Neither Firefox nor Chrome exhibit this behavior.

Is this a known IE issue?

Comment: Did you ever get to the bottom of this? Experiencing the same issue

Comment: Same issue here in IE 11. This question looks abandoned unfortunately.