# Scroll-able <ul> list going back to top when hovering a <li> element in IE

Tags: javascript, html, css, internet-explorer

I'm having the same issue as this [guy](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19799835/ul-with-vertical-scroll-jumps-to-top-in-ie9).

Only in IE, (11 inclusive), I am able to scroll my < ul >< li > list but when hovering over a < li > element, it gets scrolled all the way to the top.

```
    <div class="coursedirectory-sub_links">
        <ul>
            <c:if test="${not empty ccList}">

                <c:forEach var="ccMap" items="${ccList}">
                    <li><a href="/web/${ccMap['id']}">${ccMap['title']}</a></li>
                </c:forEach>

            </c:if>
                <li id="past-courses">Past Courses</li>
                <c:if test="${not empty pcList}">
                    <c:forEach var="pc" items="${pcList}">
                        <li><a href="/web/${pc['id']}">${pc.title}</a></li>
                    </c:forEach>
                </c:if>
        </ul> 
    </div>


.coursedirectory-sub_links ul {     
    background: none repeat scroll 0 0 #FCFCFC;     
    list-style: none outside none;
    margin-left: 0;
    margin-right: 1px !important;
    position: absolute;    
    z-index: 150;    
    padding: 0px 5px;
    right: -10em;
    max-height: 400px;
    overflow: auto;
    padding-right: 15px; }

.coursedirectory-sub_links ul li{
    text-align:center; 
    border-bottom:1px solid #e2e2e2;
    min-width:130px; 
 } 
.coursedirectory-sub_links ul li:hover { background-color: #EEEEEE; }
```

Comment: Same issue. Seems nobody knows why this happens as neither question has been answered.